# iframe inside noscript tag

Tags: html, iframe, noscript

(it might be already asked here but I did not found it, so please excuse if it is a double)

I have a Iframe in a noscript.

```
<noscript>
    <iframe src=...></iframe>
</noscript>
```

**In the case the user turned ON JavaScrript:**
Will in this case the iframe not load at all, or will it load but will not be displayed in the browser ? I ask this because I see that other code inside the  is not fully ignored, it is just not displayed you can find the text with CTRL-F

**In the case the user turned OFF JavaScrript:**
In this case it is clear the browser will load load the page in the source of the iframe, but will $GLOBAL Variables in the main site be accessible in the Site loaded in the iframe ?

Answer (score 1):

It will load only when the browser doesn't support Javascript, or you turn it off in developer settings

Answer (score 0):

It will not load at all. You can test it in Chrome Developer Tools -> Network. When you use it with 'noscript', the address in 'src' parameter will not appear there, but it appears without 'noscript'.